# Accessing a package from multiple locations in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, package, subdirectory

So I have a package that contains several common functions used by different programs. Each of these programs has it's own folder. So essentially I have the following:

```
folder/
folder/commonFunc/
folder/commonFunc/__init__.py
folder/commonFunc/package.py
folder/Program/
folder/program/function.py
```

and so on..

Assuming that all the programs have to remain in separate folders, is there any way I can access the package from a folder inside the parent directory. If so, how would I go about doing this.

Thanks and sorry if its a bit confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Put this on function.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../commonFunc")
import init
import package
```